# Is it possible to run a duplicate bash script while using the original also?

Tags: bash

I use [todo-txt](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli) to manage my todo lists. I think it's a great tool but I wish that I could have more lists, the way it works now is that there is one bash script `todo.sh` that manages one list with multiple entries. I want to have multiple lists. Is it possible create a copy of of `todo.sh` and then change all the environment variables in the copy and the config files and have two working copies of the script under a different name existing together? Then is bassically what I tried but it didn't work and I ended up getting the following error: `Fatal Error:  is not a directory`

More precisley I tried to:

- copy todo.sh -> todo2.sh
- copy todo.cfg -> todo2.cfg
- change directories in config file where todo2.sh will write to
- change environment variables in config files and using "replace all" in sublime changed the same variables in todo2.sh
- adjusted my .zshrc file to reference the appropriate commands

The main place where I think I may have gone astray is with renaming the environment variables. I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is possible. I've zipped up all the files that I'm working with, they can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bze975WJ_w5KM21QRVZZblFidzQ

Edit: with @cb0's method:

```
~ pwd
/Users/max
~ ls | grep todo
todo
todo-projects
todo.cfg
todo2
~ ls todo
README.md    done.txt     evidence.log report.txt   todo.txt     todo.txt.bak
~ ls todo2
~ cd .todo
~/.todo ls -a
.         ..        .DS_Store .todo.cfg list2
```

> /Users/max/.todo/.todo.cfg

```
# Your todo.txt directory
export TODO_DIR="/Users/max/todo"

# Your todo/done/report.txt locations
export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt"
export DONE_FILE="$TODO_DIR/done.txt"
export REPORT_FILE="$TODO_DIR/report.txt"
```

> /Users/max/.todo/list2/.todo2.cfg

```
# Your todo.txt directory
export TODO_DIR="/Users/max/todo2"

# Your todo/done/report.txt locations
export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt"
export DONE_FILE="$TODO_DIR/done.txt"
export REPORT_FILE="$TODO_DIR/report.txt"
```

> /Users/max/.zshrc

```
alias t='todo.sh -d /Users/max/.todo/.todo.cfg'
alias t2='todo.sh -d /Users/max/.todo/list2/.todo2.cfg'
```

Comment: Did you use the makefile ?

Comment: Use "todo.sh -d todo2.cfg" ? No need to change todo.sh

Comment: If you really want to use a copy of todo.sh I think your t2 alias should use todo2.sh, i.e: alias t2='todo2.sh -d /Users/max/.todo/list2/.todo2.cfg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy the script. I just had a look at it and got it working using 2 different todo lists.

Let's say you have installed a single copy of the script somewhere in your system and can call it with `todo.sh`.
Now you have your existing config under `~/.todo/config` with this content:

```
export TODO_DIR=$(dirname "$0")
export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt"
export DONE_FILE="$TODO_DIR/done.txt"
export REPORT_FILE="$TODO_DIR/report.txt"
```

So your tasks will be saved in differen files under "~/.todo/".

Now you want to create a second todo list. Therefore create a second directory, e.g. under `~/.todo/list2/`. Then copy `~/.todo/config` to `~/.todo/list2/configList2` and edit it like this:

```
export TODO_DIR=~/.todo/list2/
export TODO_FILE="$TODO_DIR/todo.txt"
export DONE_FILE="$TODO_DIR/done.txt"
export REPORT_FILE="$TODO_DIR/report.txt"
```

You now created a second config file which indicates that it has it's directory under ""~/.todo/list2/".

Now create a alias in your ".bashrc" or ".zshrc" like this.

```
alias todo2="todo.sh -d ~/.todo/list2/config"
```

This will just call `todo.sh` but also specify a config file parameter `-d`.
Now reload the file using source.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now you have 2 list that you can use. Lets first add a item to first list:

```
>todo.sh list
full:
-- TODO: 0 of 0 tasks shown

>todo.sh add "List 1, ToDo Item"
>todo.sh list                    
sh: todo.sh full:
2 List 1, ToDo item
-- TODO: 1 of 1 tasks shown
```

And then another one to second list.

```
>todo2 list 
sh: todo.sh
full:
-- TODO: 0 of 0 tasks shown

>todo2 add "List 2, ToDo item"
>todo2 list                    
sh: todo.sh
full:
1 List 2, ToDo Item
--
TODO: 1 of 1 tasks shown
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I tried your method but wasn't able to get it working. Please see edit. What am I missing here?

Comment: The directory list in "/Users/max/todo2" does not yield any folder content. Please make sure there are empty "done.txt", and "todo.txt" files in that directory. The rest looks like here and is working properly :(

Comment: I had a typo in in my `zshrc`, changing `/User/max/.todo/list2/.todo2.cfg'` to `/Users/max/.todo/list2/.todo2.cfg'` solved the problem. After that the script created the done.txt and todo.txt files for me. :)

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look at the code, I would say the obvious solution would be to copy the entire directory in which the script is installed.

Comment: I think the problem is that if I do that then they share config files and if I change the config files I'm wondering if I need to change the environment variables too. Were you able to get both scripts running concurrently? What I need help with is figuring out which config settings I need to change and which I can leave alone

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. I just looked at the code and saw that it used the location of the script to determine which files to read.